# Is Zend Framework inspired in other frameworks or ideas?

Tags: php, zend-framework, cakephp, frameworks, symfony1

There are a lot of PHP frameworks inspired by Ruby on Rails (CakePHP, Akelos, symfony). Is Zend Framework inspired in other frameworks or ideas? Do you have references (websites, books, etc) talking about it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, all of the frameworks are inspired by one another. In fact, there is a Working Group among a number of the frameworks to collaborate on useful ideas and improve compatibility in general. At present, there are members from CakePHP, Zend Framework, Solar, Agavi, Lithium, Doctrine, Symfony, Typo3, PEAR, Joomla, phpBB, and Drupal.

I am in the group but serve as a member at large mostly listening in on discussions and occasionally asking a question or three.

Comment: Huh, interesting. There's collaboration? Tell more about that working group. Linky?

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/php-standards - It's not open for general membership, but requires you to earn your way in by either being a representative of a framework and/or active in the community.

Answer (score 4):

Zend Framework is as much a framework as PEAR is. (And quite often you hear ZF [classified](http://www.killerphp.com/articles/pear-vs-zend-framework/) as PEARs successor.) Overall it's better classified as library, because it's less a coherent building block and practically more an asortment of features.

Answer (score 1):

I was greatly inspired by Zend Framework for my own framework Peak (http://code.google.com/p/peakphp/). Of course it is not as complete as Zend, but it was not the main goal. I wanted a lighter MVC layer while retaining the ability to use most of the standalone Zend Framework components.

I love the result and the speed of Peak and I use it for a few medium-sized sites. I continue to develop and test it, hoping to make it public soon.